# Checking out repository on work group computers

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a local repository and its URL is `file:///F:/subversion/MyProject`
And I checked out `MyProject` to my local machine....it works fine..

But when I try to CheckOut on a WorkGroup Computer using

URL: `file:///Server_Name/F:/subversion/MyProject` .. it gives an error like

`Error: Unable to open an ra_local session to url.`

`Error: Unable to open repository file:///Server_Name/F:/subversion/MyProject`

I also tried `Server_Name/file:///F:/subversion/MyProject`

Any help would be highly apprecialble..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not access a repository which is not on your local harddrive via the file:/// mechanism.
It's a [bad idea](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share) and you **will** get into troubles in the future. The only question is *how long* it will take until your repository is corrupt, not *whether* it will happen.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
file:///Server_Name/F:/subversion/MyProject
```

Is not the right way to address the F: drive on a remote machine. You need to set up a share on the machine and then address it using

```
\\servername\sharename\......
```

If you encounter problems with this specifically, you're better off asking on Stack Overflow's sister site, superuser.com.

This method is perfectly fine for a small number of clients in a local network. You could, however, also consider setting up a proper SVN Server like [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com).